# Как программно получить список всех разрешений (permissions) из Android Manifest

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, manifest

В связи с тем, что с 1 ноября 2018 года обязали во всех опубликованных в Google Play Market приложениях установить "targetSdkVersion=26", остро встает необходимость обработки всех разрешений приложения.

В связи с этим, стало актуальным получение списка наименований всех разрешений из Манифеста с дальнейшей их обработкой.

Подскажите какими способами это можно осуществить!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Utility` класс, который позволяет получать разрешения, используемые в файле манифеста

```
public final class PermissionUtils {

private PermissionUtils() {
}

/**
 * Retrieves permissions listed in the manifest file
 * @param context Context
 * @return Returns String array of permissions
 */
public static String[] retrievePermissions(Context context) {
    try {
        return context
                .getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS)
                .requestedPermissions;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("This should have never happened.", e);
    }
}
}
```